# creating typescript definitions for YUI 2

Tags: typescript

I want to use typescript in our project that uses [YUI 2](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/) so I am trying to create a definition file for it.

What should the definition for using

```
new YAHOO.widget.Panel('test');
```

look like?

I tried something like

```
declare module YAHOO {
  export module util {
    export interface Panel {
      (id: string);
    } 
  }
}
```

but I always get

```
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'YAHOO'
```

when running tsc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
declare module YAHOO{
    export module widget{
        export class Panel{
            constructor(element:string);
        }
    }
}

new YAHOO.widget.Panel('test');
```

[Try it online.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20module%20YAHOO%7B%0D%0A%09export%20module%20widget%7B%0D%0A%09%09export%20class%20Panel%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09constructor%28element%3astring%29;%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20YAHOO.widget.Panel%28%27test%27%29;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try...

```
module YAHOO.widget {
    export class Panel {
        constructor(public id: string) {

        }

    }

}

var panel = new YAHOO.widget.Panel('TEST');
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20YAHOO.widget%20%7B%0A%09export%20class%20Panel%20%7B%0A%09%09constructor(public%20id%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20panel%20%3D%20new%20YAHOO.widget.Panel(%22TEST%22)%3B%0A%0A

Comment: thanks for that quick reply, when I try to put that into my yahoo.d.ts I get the following errors:

**error TS1082**: Parameter property declarations cannot be used in an ambient context.
**error TS1037**: Implementations are not allowed in ambient contexts.